# USB Crypto Token with Open API

Tags: java, macos, encryption, usb

I am looking for a USB Crypto token that I can use to encrypt and decrypt files.  Symmetric encryption is all that's really required, but I need to be able to set the encryption key.

It needs to have an open API so I can talk to it directly from my programs.  A Java interface would be great, but I can write my own JNI if needed.  It also needs to work with Mac OSX.

I've Googled quite a bit for a solution.  There are many different crypto keys out there, but many of their business models are not very open and they require you to fill out long forms and be contacted by salespeople before even giving you a price.